# combing two linq expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, expression

I have two linq expressions I want to combine but my code gives me an error The binary operator And is not defined for the types `` 'System.Func`2[Web.Entities.Customer,System.Boolean]' `` and `` 'System.Func`2[Web.Entities.Customer,System.Boolean]' ``.

I have 2 expressions for example...

```
 Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter = c => c.Active;
 Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filterz = c => c.Visible;
```

i then combine them

```
 filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(Expression.And(filter, filterz));
```

Any help regarding this problem?

thanks....

here is the updateed code given on the answer below.

```
public class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{

    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}

filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(
                        new SwapVisitor(filter.Parameters[0], filterz.Parameters[0]).Visit(filter.Body), filterz.Body), filterz.Parameters)
```

Comment: What do you want to get in the result?

Comment: i want to pass the combined expression to my generic repository and pass back all customers that are active and visible. I already have a working generic repository that i send in an expression filter and pass back the database table values through the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already can use your expressions in repository without outer combining them:

```
var yourContext = getContext();
var filtered = yourContext.Where(filter).Where(filter2);
```

Combining is unnecessary in this case and this approach will work either without affecting to efficiency.

**If you need combining:**

Try use the following visitor helper:

```
public class ReplacementVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldExpr;
    private readonly Expression _newExpr;
    public ReplacementVisitor(Expression oldExpr, Expression newExpr)
    {
        _oldExpr = oldExpr;
        _newExpr = newExpr;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldExpr)
            return _newExpr;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

We need it because, your filtering expressions use different parameters instances. For combining we need them to use the same parameter instance. This class helps us to do the following:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter = c => c.Active;
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filterz = c => c.Visible;

var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
var visitor1 = new ReplacementVisitor(filter.Parameters[0], newParameter);
var visitor2 = new ReplacementVisitor(filterz.Parameters[0], newParameter);

var newLambda = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.AndAlso(
        visitor1.Visit(filter.Body),
        visitor2.Visit(filterz.Body)
    ),
    newParameter
);
```

Comment: I need to combine because deppending on the conditions set in an enum will operate different filtering conditions. The above code is stripped down basic version.

Comment: This does not work either. It goes through the helper method but nothing is returned.

Comment: Which method? `newLambda` in my example is a combined expression you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter1 = c => c.Active;
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter2 = c => c.Visible;

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");

var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
                Expression.AndAlso(
                    Expression.Invoke(filter1,parameter),
                    Expression.Invoke(filter2,parameter)
                ),parameter
            );
```

Comment: Are you sure he needs bitwise AND operation?

Answer (score 2):

if you are working with the same `Customer` in each filter you have, than you can try:

```
        Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter = c => c.Active;
        Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter2 = c => c.Visible;

        var body = Expression.AndAlso(filter.Body, Expression.Invoke(filter2, filter.Parameters[0]));

        filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(body, filter.Parameters);
        var applyFilter = filter.Compile();

        var customer = new Customer() { Visible = true, Active = true};
        Console.WriteLine(applyFilter(customer));

        customer.Active = false;
        Console.WriteLine(applyFilter(customer));

        customer.Visible = false;
        Console.WriteLine(applyFilter(customer));
```

Comment: This will not work, because bodies of expressions uses different parameters instances.